# Alternate syntax so I can have both a safe navigation and a monad unwrapping operator?

Tags: syntax, monads

I'd like to have both a safe navigation operator and monad unwrapping operator.

Safe navigation is like the feature in TypeScript:

```
fn() => print(Some(k)?.property) // prints Some(k.property)
fn() => print(None?.property) // prints None
```

This is very useful for transversing nested structures with members that may or may not exist.

However, I'd also like a monad unwrapping operator like rust has:

```
fn() => print(Some(k)?.property) // prints k.property, function returns Some(())
fn() => print(None(k)?.property) // prints nothing, function returns None
```

Note that monad unwrapping works at a function level while safe navigation works at a expression level. Ideally I'd have both, but both contractually use the `?` symbol creating ambiguity.

Both of these work on many other monads besides `Option`

I already use `??` for null coalescing.

What other syntax can I use to disambiguate these 2 concepts? Ideally I'd like something that is already used in some other language.

Comment: I’m not really sure what the question is asking. Could you give a longer example where the difference is more obvious? Swift has implicit wrapping, so `Optional.some(1)` can just be written `1`, which might be making it a bit harder for me.

Comment: @Bbrk24 I expaned the examples a bit more, does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby uses the `&.` token for safe navigation, which can safely coexist with a `?` for monads.

```
foo&.bar # Safe navigation a la Ruby
foo?.bar # Monadic unwrap a la Rust
```

If you don't like the asymmetry between `?` for monad unwrapping and `??` for null coalescing, I'm quite fond of Perl's `//` for null coalescing. It looks like `||` (which is similar) but is clearly a different operator. Only downside is it won't work if you're using C-style comments as well.

Answer (score 3):

## Asterisk

If you're not already using it and it works with your current syntax, you could use `*.` for monad unwrapping.

```
Some(k)*.property = k.property
None(k)*.property = return None
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know any language that uses that syntax? I'm specifically looking for a established convention

Comment: @mousetail I don't, but that might just be because no languages have had these two features before. You might get to be a trendsetter!

Comment: (I'm mostly asking for established conventions to avoid being closed as opinion based, I don't actually care)

Answer (score 3):

## `.map` method

This is what Swift does. Using the example from your question:

```
func printSafe(_ x: T?) {
  print(x?.property)
}

func printMonad(_ x: T?) -> Void? {
  x.map { print($0.property) }
}
```

If you provide functional interfaces on collection types, this runs the risk of confusing `arr?.map` with `arr.map`.